# Hi.. I am making a game where I want to show top 5 score like shown in image but if I don't have 5 records in list..it show 'empty'

Tags: list, flutter

like

Statstics

1. David 430
2. Ellen 300
3. empty
4. empty
5. empty

Comment: Try adding some code or what you have already tried first. The point of stack over flow is to help not just create brand new code for you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a local database using sqlflite package and store data in it.

The link of the package:
https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

It requires you know about databases and sql to be able to store data and keep the top 5 scores only in the data

but it will do the job for you.